# Get data from businessaccount

Tags: facebook, types, get, facebook-c#-sdk, account

When I use the c# sdk and quering my personal "normal" account everything works fine.
But when I use the same settings/permissions with a BusinessAccount I always get null as result.
For example if I do

```
me = this.FBClient.Get("/me")
```

with a normal/personal account I'm receiving the data as expected. But on a business account it always returns null and throws NO error.

Is there a difference in getting data from a businessaccount?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Business accounts do not have Facebook profiles, they are just for ad management. Hence, they do not return anything from /me.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. Ok is it possible to determin which kind of account the current account is during the authprocess? Surely, I could do it by checking if /"me" is null but is there a proper way to do this?

Comment: Just to clarify, when you log in with your business account to Facebook.com it goes directly to the ads manage page correct? If so then it should not be possible to auth an app with it at all. How are you trying to auto the app?

Comment: Yes it does. Why should this not be possible? If I go to the App-overview I can see my App an the permissions which were requested.

Comment: Hi Stephen, Facebook recently started preventing business accounts from installing Application. These accounts are only intended for use in managing advertisements. As business accounts can no longer install applications we no longer support them calling the Graph API and hence most call will not work for them.

Comment: Does this mean that in future I will not be able to create events for example on a business account through an app?