# Installing applications with a business account

Tags: facebook

I have created an application on Facebook and am trying to prevent business accounts from installing the application. I understand that business accounts (and by extension pages) can not install applications. This understanding comes from a few posts I have come across here on Stack Overflow posted by users on the Facebook support team -

- [Can I add the "login using facebook" feature for my fb business page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10419172/can-i-add-the-login-using-facebook-feature-for-my-fb-business-page) (answered by [igy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/21062/Igy))
- [Get data from businessaccount](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7227208/get-data-from-businessaccount/7229425#7229425) (answered by [Jonathan Dean](https://stackoverflow.com/users/850570/jonathan-dean))

A picture is worth a thousand words, so here is a screen shot proving that I am able to install an application with a business account -

[image]

As you can see from the settings page, this is indeed a business account and it has installed an application (SomeApp).

Whether or not this is a bug (which I believe it is) is **not** my question here.

My question is how can I detect such a business account? I am aware that before installing the application I have no information on the user so I'll have to detect this after the account has installed the application.

So far my thoughts are to inspect the following fields -

- `first_name`
- `last_name`

I was considering the `gender` field too, but I believe that this can be set to private.

Comment: [Here is another screen shot](http://i.imgur.com/QywP7Qe.png) of some more permissions this business account granted to the application. The list goes on...

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong, but in any cases, a business account will never return any information, even the user ID (I think). So for example, in javascript, you can check if the response.id is returned. If not, this user is not allowed to continue the process.