# How can I get the type of a Facebook user?

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api

I'm making an application that allows connection by means of Facebook users. I have two users :

- The first user is a personal type.
- The second user is a business type.

When I register with a personal user, PHP is getting all the personal information(user name, last name..) correctly, but when I register with a business user, PHP isn't getting the information.

I think the problem is the type of user, correct?

Comment: Duplicated/related/I'm also looking at a similar problem - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14807994/installing-applications-with-a-business-account

Answer (score 0):

According to the Facebook Help Center, a business account is not allowed to use apps. So yes, the user's type is the problem.